# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'products'

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I am creating an Invoicing system. I have multiple .py files in the project. On of the pages is where a user can add products that are saved to an sqlite3 database. In a different invoicing.py file, I want to list the product names in a combobox so that the user can select one. I can't seem to figure out how to connect the two .py files correctly so that it will call the data from the products.db table.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3
from tkinter import ttk


def save_invoice():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('invoices.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS invoices (
                invoice_number text,
                customer_name text,
                item_description text,
                item_quantity real,
                total real
                )""")

    invoice_number = invoice_number_entry.get()
    customer_name = customer_name_entry.get()
    item_description = item_cmb.get()
    item_price = float(item_price_entry.get())
    item_quantity = float(item_quantity_entry.get())
    #total = float(tree.total.get())

    c.execute("""INSERT INTO invoices (invoice_number, customer_name, item_description, item_price, item_quantity) 
                VALUES (?,?,?)""", (invoice_number, customer_name, item_description, item_price, item_quantity))#, total))

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    status_lbl.config(text="Invoice saved successfully")

def prodnames():
    item = sqlite3.connect('products.db')
    i = item.cursor()

    i.execute("SELECT name FROM products")
    i.close()

def clear_item():
    item_quantity_entry.delete(0, tkinter.END)
    item_quantity_entry.insert(0, "1")
    item_cmb.delete(0, tkinter.END)

def add_item(self, item_quantity_entry, item_description_entry, item_price_entry, tree, clear_item):
    quantity = int(item_quantity_entry.get())
    items = item_description_entry.get()
    price = float(item_price_entry.get())
    total = [quantity*price]
    invoice_items = [items, quantity, price, total]

    tree.insert('', 0, values=invoice_items)
    clear_item()


app = tk.Tk()
app.title("Invoicing System")

invoice_create_label = tk.Label(text="Create a new invoice")
invoice_create_label.grid(row=0, column=2)

invoice_number_label = tk.Label(text="Invoice Number:")
invoice_number_label.grid(row=2, column=0)

invoice_number_entry = tk.Entry()
invoice_number_entry.grid(row=3, column=0)

customer_name_label = tk.Label(text="Customer Name:")
customer_name_label.grid(row=2, column=1)

customer_name_entry = tk.Entry()
customer_name_entry.grid(row=3, column=1)

item_description_label = tk.Label(text="Item Description:")
item_description_label.grid(row=2, column=2)

#item_description_entry = tk.Entry()
#item_description_entry.grid(row=3, column=2)
course=prodnames()
item_cmb = ttk.Combobox(app, value=course)
item_cmb.grid(row=3, column=2)


item_price_label = tk.Label(text="Item Price:")
item_price_label.grid(row=2, column=3)

item_price_entry = tk.Entry()
item_price_entry.grid(row=3, column=3)

item_quantity_label = tk.Label(text="Item Quantity")
item_quantity_label.grid(row=2, column=4)

item_quantity_entry = tk.Entry()
item_quantity_entry.grid(row=3, column=4)

add_button = tk.Button(text="Add to invoice", command=add_item)
add_button.grid(row=7, column=2)

save_button = tk.Button(text="Save Invoice", command=save_invoice)
save_button.grid(row=9, column=0)

columns = ('items', 'price', 'quantity', 'total')
tree = ttk.Treeview(app, columns=columns, show="headings")
tree.heading('items', text='Items')
tree.heading('price', text='Price')
tree.heading('quantity', text='Quantity')
tree.heading('total', text='Total')

tree.grid(row=8, column=0, columnspan=5, padx=20, pady=10)

status_lbl = tk.Label(text="")
status_lbl.grid(row=9, column=1)

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's gonna be hard to tell without knowing what newprod is. If it's a function, maybe calling it will help? `course=save_prod().products...`?

Comment: I just updated my code there. newprod.py is the other file where products.db is created. I've updated the code and it runs with no errors, however does not list products saved in the database in the combobox

Comment: It is better to change the question title because it does not match the question any more.  Note that `prodname()` returns `None`, it should return the records retrieved from database table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prodnames()` returns `None`. You need to return records retrieved from the database table:

```py
def prodnames():
    item = sqlite3.connect('products.db')
    i = item.cursor()

    i.execute("SELECT name FROM products")
    names = [row[0] for row in i.fetchall()]  # get all the names
    i.close()

    return names
```